# vim: how to specify arrow keys

Tags: vim

In vim, when using `map` commands you must specify keys. For example `<CR> <ESC> <F1>`. What are the corresponding ones for the arrow keys?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If you don't know the internal code for a certain key, type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and then the function key. For example, this
sequence followed by the up arrow key will output:

```
<Up>
```

You can learn more about this command in the documentation for both [insert](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-K)
and [command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-K) mode. The specific ways to map a special key are given in the
documentation with the tag [`:map-special-keys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-special-keys). Additionally, you can find a
handy table with [`:h key-notation`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation).

Comment: The more general escape is <C-v> before special keys. _Unfortunately, on windows this key has been remapped to <C-q> by default_. <C-k> is really for digraph composition

Comment: Yeah, it works too but I'll continue in my position :-) c-k is not only for digraphs, the help helps saying that _When {char1} is a special key, the code for that key is inserted in <> form._. I tend to use c-v to insert a ^L in text and c-k to insert a `<c-l>`.

Answer (score 44):

Quite literal:

```
<Left>
<Right>
<Up>
<Down>
```

As noted in the comments, find this and more in [this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29).

Comment: That is what I find in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29

Answer (score 19):

And

```
<C-Right>
```

for Control key and Right.

For example, I used the following mappings (in my .vimrc) to cycle through my open buffers:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> :bn<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> :bp<CR>
```